# How to rename multiple files?

Tags: bash, file-rename

In a folder I have several files with the following name-structure (I write just three examples):

```
F_001_4837_blabla1.doc
F_045_8987_blabla2.doc
F_168_9092_blabla3.doc
```

What I would do is to use a BASH command to rename all the files in my folder by deleting the first underscore and the series of zeros before the first number code obtaining:

```
F1_4837_blabla1.doc
F45_8987_blabla2.doc
F168_9092_blabla3.doc
```

Comment: Look up `rename bash command`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
shopt -s extglob

for f in *; do
  echo "$f: ${f/_*(0)/}"
  # mv "$f" "${f/_*(0)/}"   # for the actual rename
done
```

#### output

```
F_001_4837_blabla1.doc: F1_4837_blabla1.doc
F_045_8987_blabla2.doc: F45_8987_blabla2.doc
F_168_9092_blabla3.doc: F168_9092_blabla3.doc
```

## Parameter Expansion

Parameter expansion can be used to replace the content of a variable. In this case, we replace the pattern `_*(0)` with nothing.

```
${parameter/pattern/string}
       Pattern substitution.  The pattern is expanded to produce a pat-
       tern just as in pathname expansion.  Parameter is  expanded  and
       the  longest match of pattern against its value is replaced with
       string.  If pattern begins with /, all matches  of  pattern  are
       replaced   with  string.   Normally  only  the  first  match  is
       replaced.  If pattern begins with #, it must match at the begin-
       ning of the expanded value of parameter.  If pattern begins with
       %, it must match at the end of the expanded value of  parameter.
       If string is null, matches of pattern are deleted and the / fol-
       lowing pattern may be omitted.  If parameter is @ or *, the sub-
       stitution  operation  is applied to each positional parameter in
       turn, and the expansion is the resultant list.  If parameter  is
       an  array  variable  subscripted  with  @ or *, the substitution
       operation is applied to each member of the array  in  turn,  and
       the expansion is the resultant list.
```

## Extended pattern matching

Extended pattern matching allows us to use the pattern `*(0)` to match zero or more `0` characters. It needs to be enabled using the `extglob` setting.

```
If the extglob shell option is enabled using the shopt builtin, several
extended pattern matching operators are recognized.  In  the  following
description, a pattern-list is a list of one or more patterns separated
by a |.  Composite patterns may be formed using one or more of the fol-
lowing sub-patterns:

       ?(pattern-list)
              Matches zero or one occurrence of the given patterns
       *(pattern-list)
              Matches zero or more occurrences of the given patterns
       +(pattern-list)
              Matches one or more occurrences of the given patterns
       @(pattern-list)
              Matches one of the given patterns
       !(pattern-list)
              Matches anything except one of the given patterns
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It worked perfectly! Can I ask you also another thing? The filenames contains also spaces and an ugly dot before the natural ending ".doc". How can I change all the spaces and the dots, except the last one obviously, with underscores?

Comment: @Marco I would add additional renames: `f_new=${f/..doc/.doc}`, `f_new=${f_new/another/replacement}`, etc. You will find the manual to be a useful resource. Obviously those exact commands don't work, you need to play around yourself.